# Block localhost quickly in Chrome for testing AJAX failures

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, testing, localhost

When I want to test some Javascript code and how it handles a request failure. I have to stop Apache on my development machine. Make the request and then restart Apache.

It's a time consuming activity.

Is there some Chrome trick or extension where I can quickly toggle access to localhost or a domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Chrome extension that uses [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#examples) to block requests to `localhost` could work.

The extension's `manifest.json` file could look something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "localhost blocker",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

And your `background.js` file could be:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
    {urls: ["*://localhost/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
);
```